# Determinant Question

Tags: linear-algebra

This is not a homework question.

Let $A$ be an $n\times{n}$ matrix with entries in the field $F$ such that each entry is relatively prime to any other entry. What is the number of elementary matrices needed so that $E_1E_2\cdots{E_i}A=A^T$, where each $E_i$ is an elementary matrix. More generally, if we have some interdependency between the entries, what can we say about the number of elementary matrices needed to obtain $A^T$? I suspect that the answer for the first question is $n^2$.

Comment: what do you mean by relatively prime? There is no such thing in a field.

Comment: I couldn't think of a nice way to phrase that offhand. I just didn't want to include cases where a lot of the entries are the same, or maybe some rows are multiples of others, or something like that.

Comment: If your matrix is nonsingular, i believe it takes up to roughly $n^2$ operations in Gauss elimination to take it all the way to the identity, meaning the same for reversing. to get your matrix from the identity.